# Java - How to change cursor without Swing Component?

Tags: java, swing, cursor

I have a Java application that run as a background service, i.e. no GUI. But when starting it, say through a batch script, I have some preparation works to be done at the very beginning of my program (something like communicate with server).

I want a busy cursor appear at this busy moment. Is it possible to do this without using any Swing component? Thanks for any suggestion or alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a console-based "progress bar". It's possible to use Swing but it would render your solution useless in a headless environment. Drawing progress bars with characters in terminal is quite a common practice.

You can either implement it yourself or use a ready class. Just take a look at github or bitbucket and you'll find something for sure.

A busy cursor could even be displayed as a caption with alternating last character (as simple as possible), with "frames" like these (rotating bar)

```
LOADING DATA /
LOADING DATA |
LOADING DATA \
LOADING DATA -
```

Implementing something like this wouldn't take much time. We're talking about minutes here.

If the only thing that prevents you from using Swing is an appearing window, you can change its appearance thanks to [window translucency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html). This way you'd get an animated image overlaying your screen. It wouldn't work in a terminal though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but does it mean it is not possible to change the system cursor without accessing Swing or AWT API?

Comment: @VictorWong it's possible with Swing, AWT and JavaFX. It can't be done without a library providing access to the system's native libraries. You could write your own native code in C and use it in your Java program but that would be just reimplementing those libraries. A very bad idea.

Comment: @VictorWong if you want a graphical cursor, you'll have to use Swing (or another library). You can "get rid" of a window by using window translucency http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: Thanks Tom. Save me lots of time in searching the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Java AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit) I beleive you can use the setCursor of Component class to change the cursor.

More on this : http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/ChangeCursor.shtml

Comment: But according to the page you suggested, a Frame window will come out but my application doesn't need any GUI there.